# A term for "number of columns" of a matrix

Tags: terminology, matrix

Is there a single English word to denote the "number of columns" of a matrix?

For example, "dimensionality" of a $2\times 3$ matrix is $2\times 3$. I need a term for $3$ in this example. I can always just say "number of columns", of course, but could I have a single word for it?

Comment: why is that interesting/useful?

Comment: @DataD'oh, I am writing a paper where this is used frequently. There, a single term would make the text easier to read and sound lighter than using three words ever time. Think this way: what would happen if we got rid of some existing useful term (such as dimensionality) and described it every time with multiple words. That would not be convenient, would it? Just like that, I miss a term for "number of columns".

Comment: Aha, interesting! In machine learning literature the convention is to use columns to represent features/variables, so perhaps something like this might apply in your case.

Comment: Can't you propose a context where you consider $m\times n$ matrices and then simply refer to $n$?

Comment: @broncoAbierto, thank you for the idea! See my comment under George's answer for why this does not work for me.

Comment: I propose you do as Tukey would have and invent a word. How about "columnity"

Comment: @einar, unless we find a term that already exists, I would seriously consider your idea. I would not expect it to work immediately, but in the end we may recall that each useful term must have been invented at some point by people who could not do without it any longer.

Comment: Whatever you do, I would be careful to avoid terms like column "dimension" as it could be interpreted as the dimension of the column space (which may be smaller than the number of columns).

Comment: This is stretching it, but rank-nullity is a mathematical synonym for the number of columns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: @einar: put your suggestion as an answer!

Comment: Note that what you call "dimensionality" of a matrix is more commonly called simply "size".

Comment: @aivanov sure, why not

Comment: @RichardHardy If it is for a written paper, maybe a notation such as `ncol(A)` might work.  That does not "sound lighter", but maybe it would "make the text easier to read".

Comment: Why community-wiki though?

Comment: @James has the right answer right there in his comment, even though it might not sound good, it answers the question.

Comment: Using the common Cartesian x,y variables, you could use **x-dimension**

Comment: @Firebug "Rank-nullity" does not refer to the number of columns.  The words refer *separately* to two properties of the matrix--its rank and its nullity--and the hyphenated phrase is attached to the theorem that asserts the rank *plus* the nullity equals the number of columns.  Using "rank-nullity" to refer to the number of columns sounds like an unwise suggestion because it would sow confusion and introduce superfluous ideas to boot. BTW, this was made CW because it was clear from the outset that it wouldn't generate a unique valid answer.

Comment: @whuber Point taken. This removes my point about the _"right answer"_, but I still maintain that the term can be appropriated then, after all it'll be a single word with the exact intended meaning.

Comment: As per [Matrices and Determinoids, Vol I, C. E. Cullis, Page 1](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.chmm/1437148231), the number of columns is known as the _vertical order_ of a matrix. I don't see the `Answer` button so if this is useful, can someone with sufficent rep add this as an answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill, the answer button should be at the bottom of the thread.

Answer (score 18):

There is a concept of [wide and narrow data](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data), so maybe you could use the term „width“ for the number of columns after you define it in order to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is close to what I need, but I wonder if there exists a more specific term for that.

Comment: This is certainly a good idea. The frequent use of "tall and skinny" might also give you some clues.

Comment: `width` is generally its name in computer programming, so +1 from me

Answer (score 16):

Let's review your objectives:

1. You want a short, meaningful term.
2. You want it to be memorable and readable, rather than some clunky abstract mathematical or computerese construction like "let $\mathbb{A}\in\operatorname{Mat}(n,p)$" or even "$\mathbb{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}.$"
3. You want to be able to specify the number of columns explicitly, so you can distinguish (say) 3-column matrices from 2-column matrices or $p$-column matrices from $p+1$-column matrices.
4. You want it function as a noun rather than an adjectival phrase; that is, it should read like "$\mathbb A$ is a $p$-column matrix" rather than "the column count of $\mathbb A$ is $p$."
5. Evidently, even a short phrase like "$p$-column matrix" is too much!

As others have remarked, you're in the domain of creating your own terminology.  However, "columnity" (which has been proposed) has a grotesque and non-English aspect, albeit being little briefer.

If I were in this position, at the outset of the document I would introduce a term and define it, perhaps like this:

> Because we will frequently need to refer to the number of columns in a matrix, let us say that a *$p-$matrix* is any matrix with exactly $p$ columns.

That seems to meet all the objectives.  It's hard to imagine anything simpler, short of a mathematical notation (which violates objective $(2)$).  It also is consistent with long-standing mathematical terminology, which includes well-known terms like "symmetric matrix," "real matrix," "transition matrix," "rank-$p$ matrix," *etc.*

Comment: This is a good answer! I will think more and perhaps accept it.

Comment: One problem with "p-matrix" is that it's ambiguous: "p" could refer to the number of rows just as easily.  That's unless you've already specified that the matrix is nxp, in which case you would just refer to "p".  And not everyone automatically makes matrices mxp.  There's plenty of mxn matrices out there.  For a general matrix term, it should be independent of application, so you can't assume that somehow the number of columns is more interesting.  Both dimensions are important - you can't assume a reader will know you'll be talking about the number of columns instead of the number of rows.

Comment: @gms It's not in the least ambiguous if you follow the full prescription in this answer!

Comment: @whuber,  I realized that a sentence explains the convention.  My point was that sentence would always be needed, because "p" doesn't strongly enough suggest columns rather than rows, rank, power,  probabilities with rows or columns summing to 1, symmetric positive definite (my guess if I saw the the term without the explanation), "complex square matrix' (a Google result). The next author might just as easily have a sentence defining a p-matrix as one with p rows, or one with rank p.   If the convention always requires the explanatory sentence, it fails the short and concise test.

Comment: @gms I do not interpret the question as asking for a way to create a new convention: I have only interpreted it as looking for a way to solve a particular problem of communication, as I outlined in the list of objectives that begin my answer.

Comment: @whuber  Fair enough.  But I interpret the question as a general one, with the answer to be re-used.  Strictly speaking, the answer to the question is "no".  We're just talking about ways to address that, and communications are most effective if they're the most obvious, requiring the least explanation.  Just referring to p after defining the matrix does that, and "columnity" somewhat does that, as does "domain dimension", although that's only obvious to the more mathematically-inclined.

Comment: @gms Based solely on the text of the question, I think your interpretation is reasonable.  The comment thread after the question suggests my narrower interpretation is the intended one.

Answer (score 13):

Personally I would denote the matrix as $$X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$$ and use $p$ as a reference (assuming your matrix is composed of real values!).

Also note that the notation [p >> n](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1CDGOYI_enDE763DE763&hl=en-GB&ei=MdkOWpbTIpDIwQLStqCQDA&q=%E2%80%9Ep%20%3E%3E%20n%E2%80%9C&oq=%E2%80%9Ep%20%3E%3E%20n%E2%80%9C&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...0.0.2.4630.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.0.0....0.ui8taJ7e4tI) is quite widely used to describe the 'short and wide' datasets, e.g. datasets where the number of rows (observations) is significantly lower than number of columns (features). There is an area of Statistics known has 'High-dimensional statistics' that deals with these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a nice idea for a workaround, and I am already using it. But this does not answer the question which specifically asks for a term (a single English word).

Comment: Usually in Machine Learning and Statistics, each column corresponds to the dimensionality of the data or the number of covariates - I guess you could use these if you need a single word. I would recommend using what I suggested in my answer if you are writing a paper.

Comment: George, as I said, I am already using it. Thanks again!

Comment: Also also note that `\gg` typesets much nicer than `>>`.

Answer (score 10):

I propose you do as Tukey would have done and invent a word. It is of course OK to define new terminology as long as we are explicit about it. As you say it might not gain immediate traction, but it would still work within the scope of your paper. My personal suggestion is

> **columnity** [n.] of A: the extent to which A is columnar

An edit: Thinking a bit about my light-hearted suggestion here I felt I should also add that **width** is my preference. It's short and sweet and follows the excellent tip in Orwell's *Politics and the English language* to never use a long word where a short one will do.

Comment: Surely you mean it to be a noun so he can say "of columnity 3"? (but +1 anyway)

Comment: I agree with @mdewey, I‘ve never heard columnity to be used as an adjective. But I‘m not native English speaker, maybe that’s why... P.S. you‘ve got my +1, of course.

Comment: @mdewey you are right of course, I was in a bit of a rush writing it down

Comment: That does sound a lot like "calumny" and "calamity".

Comment: @Acccumulation it's quite fortunate in a sense, a calamity being what you often get with too many columns

Comment: Yup.  Columnity and rowfulness.  Two wonderful words.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem They certainly are full of cromulentness.

Comment: You mean cromulentia!

Answer (score 8):

I like "width", as suggested by aivanov.  It is difficult to be more specific, without being longer and without using several words.  If several words are ok, then we are back to "number of columns".

An alternative is to reformulate: Instead of saying:

> $A$ is a matrix of width 3.

or

> The number of columns of $A$ is 3.

why not just say

> $A$ has 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do appreciate it, but it does not answer the question which specifically asks for a term (a single English word). If I needed ways of rephrasing, I would have asked for that specifically.

Comment: @RichardHardy Well, I think you should give some examples of the sentences where you would like to use the term you searching for. It's a bit difficult to know what you want without a precise context.

Comment: @amoeba, see my comment under Glen_b's answer.

Comment: @RichardHardy While the question you are technically asking is quite simple, it makes the appearance that there is an underlying question of style.  Often, the most elegant solution is not the most direct solution.  So don't complain if the proposed answers seem to go into different directions than you anticipate..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The question is phrased directly and the intention is that it makes the appearance of what it is. The question is hopefully precise enough to be understood in the same way by everyone. I have made no complaints so far and do not intend to make any (stating the fact is not a complaint). I appreciate the effort of everyone who has posted an answer, inlcuding yourself. It is worth noting that even the answers that do not answer the question may be useful for someone else with a related query at some point in the future; that is a nice thing to know.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear why it's important to have only a single-word term.

I'd say that for most purposes don't be afraid of three shortish words: "number of columns"; the very term you began with, which served to perfectly convey the idea you asked about.

It is a mere 5 syllables, it's not a strain to say or write.

A term consisting of just a few common words is likely to be *less* of an intellectual effort to grasp on the fly than one longish or unfamiliar one.

There may well be four or five terms that might serve, but if I was only writing it a few times, I would feel the strong inclination to go back and edit such a term out and replace it with "number of columns".

If I would need to write about a specific case many times, I'd start with something like "Let $X$ be an $n\times p$ matrix" and then refer to $p$ thereafter; or if I had to refer to the number of columns of many matrices, to have a notation like "denote the number of columns of a matrix $A$ as $c_A$", or something similar as suited the circumstances.

Comment: My question was not about whether 3 words is better than 1, there was no intention to discuss that. The point was, does the term exist and if so, what is it. It is a pity a lot of discussion in this thread did not focus on the actual question. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I realize you ask for a single word and I don't give one; nevertheless, people looking for such a word who locate your post may be encouraged by my answer to use three instead. If I induce even a few such people to stick to three words for preference I think the answer will have been worth the effort.

Comment: In that sense, you are of course right. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like mostly a specific language (English) problem. In German language this would be much less problematic. The term **'spaltenanzahl'** is not a strange word and regularly used. So you may consider introducing 'column-count' or 'column count' (while column-number would be ambiguous), or accept 'number of columns' as not that complex after all (and can often be written simpler with other sentence constructions e.g. 'matrix $M$ has $w$ columns').

Some background on the article and examples of sentences would help to look for different terms. One could use width and length or (as Sylvester, origin of the term matrix, did use) breadth and depth. Maybe based on what the matrix actually presents (e.g. system of equations, a polynomial, a vector space, etc.) other terms could be used.

Depending on your article background (or maybe no, independent from the public for your article, maybe only if you do something entirely new) I would advise to not use any newly invented term, and neither use some existing term (which must be an archaic term).

You have to ask yourself whether the poverty in the English language, not containing a simple synonym for the German term spaltenanzahl, is worth introducing something fancy that may only be confusing.

Comment: Cool suggestions, breadth/depth has a cool ring to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend avoiding to talk about matrices at all. Most applications that deal with matrices are in principle not interested in matrices at all, but rather in *[linear mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) between vector spaces*. The basis-expanded representation of a mapping $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, thus the column-count $n$ is the **domain dimension** of the mapping.

Likewise, the row count would be the **codomain dimension**.

These aren't single words, but they're reasonably short yet precise.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion from a mathematical point of view (+1).  Since the most fundamental matrix considered in statistics is a data matrix, in which columns can have different data types, and such matrices *cannot* be conceived of as representing linear transformations of real spaces, the applicability of this suggestion is limited.

Answer (score 1):

go for width \ height as mentioned
its pretty clear what you mean and even a child knows what those words mean
(providing the array is always represented from the same viewpoint)

Of course if you go into arrays of more than 3 dimensions (height, width, depth) it gets a little tricky and is probably better to use matrix notation

Answer (score 1):

There does exist and English word columnarity which means the property of being columnar. So saying a matrix of columnarity 3 would seem quite natural.

Comment: How is "a matrix of columnarity 3" better or simpler than "a matrix with 3 columns"? Sometimes it seems best to KISS.

Comment: @user3697176 not when you want to refer to this very property. Compare `given the number of columns of a matrix we can calculate [...]` vs `given the columnarity we can calculate`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you use your matrix for representing data. Usually, columns represent the different features and rows are different data points, as the data store in the figure below ([ref](http://cdn-s4.tarikmoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/row-store-v-column-store.gif)).

[image: row store]

This then extends to the the dimension of useful matrices, e. g. for mixing these features into a new dimension.

In that context, the number of columns is the number of dimensions of your feature space, that is, simply *dimensionality*.